# Reconciliation in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a question so basically react native uses three threads

JS thread,Shadow thread,UI Thread

So my doubt is js thread is responsible for running the js executing render method but then where does reconciliation or diffing algorithm is applied is it in same js thread or it happens in Shadow Thread

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/architecture/threading-model